# How to resolve "Could not find installable ISAM" in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a module that updates a SharePoint list through VBA, I have some users that cannot perform this operation. Users that are running Excel 2013 receive a runtime error. I am not sure where the mistake is or how I can rewrite my code to accommodate older versions. The error highlights `.Open`. Here is my VBA Code:

```
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mySQL As String

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [opsmangement]   WHERE [branch]= '" & Sheet18.Range("A10").Value & "'"

With cnt
.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://us.cs.us-dns.com/sites/downtown/;LIST={21B3D896-995F-461F-BDB8-F8DB41128229};"
.Open
End With
```

Comment: Microsoft.ACE is the driver for Microsoft Access databases.  Do your users have Microsoft Access?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The user getting the Error does not have Access installed. I was unaware that it had to be installed. Is there a library I can reference instead?

Comment: This is probably what you need: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you for the info and link. I was trying to avoid having to download a driver since its company computers. Time to make a call to IT Department